# Searching a List of Tuples in Parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, tuples

I have a large list of tuples (1,000) of integers in the form of Tuple. How can I go about doing a List.Find and the list searched in parallel? I am searching on both parts of the tuple (i.e the left and right element).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language? C#? Java?

Answer (score 0):

Logically split your list into chunks. Give each thread a sublist to search. It's easier (from an example perspective) if you use an array because you could specify the bounds within the array where each thread is allowed to search.

For example if you have 3 threads and an array of length n. You can let the first thread search in elements from 0-n/3; the second thread searches from n/3 to 2*n/3; the third thread searches from 2*n/3 to n.

Caveat: Having 3 searching threads doesn't mean the searching happens in parallel. You might not have 3 cores/CPUs available on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If `list` is the name of your collection and `x` is the value you are searching for, this should do it (assuming you are working with .net 4.0):

```
var result = list.AsParallel().Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 == x).ToList();
```